# What to do when a user reposts their own question (possibly for reputation)?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

Recently, @LostSoul asked this question: [Is there a better way to guess possible unknown variables without brute force than I am doing? Machine learning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49890536/is-there-a-better-way-to-guess-possible-unknown-variables-without-brute-force-th)

However, around 6 years ago, @LostSoul asked an almost exact duplicate of this question: [How to approach number guessing game(with a twist) algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694978/how-to-approach-number-guessing-gamewith-a-twist-algorithm?rq=1)

Then, (a few months after the first quesion), @LostSoul asked another almost exact duplicate: [Applying machine learning to a guessing game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057936/applying-machine-learning-to-a-guessing-game?rq=1)

A few more (from @PatrickHofman):

[On math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70798/how-to-approach-number-guessing-gamewith-a-twist-algorithm)

[Also, on stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341588/is-there-machine-learning-approach-to-guessing-combinations-game-as-opposed-to-b)

This previous question was very well-received and received many upvotes as well as a bounty. The question which @LostSoul asked recently is essentially asking the same question. Again, this question was well-received and received many upvotes as well as a (lesser) bounty.

I'm surprised this 'new' question wasn't flagged as a duplicate, especially as the 'original' question was third in the 'Related Questions' section (and the other one was fourth).

**What should be done about this 'new' question?** I've flagged the question as a duplicate, but it's unlikely that there's going to be more people flagging it, as the question is now inactive.

Comment: if you really think it's a dup you flag and you can comment to ask for more clarification about why he asked the same question .. maybe after 6 years things have changed. I would be suprised if he asked the same question 1month or 1week after.

Comment: I dont agree, he gave a bounty of 500 so do the calculation and see how much he earned and how much he spent. --> https://stackoverflow.com/users/640558/lostsoul?tab=reputation. And suddenly thinking about earning rep after 6 years, i don't think so

Comment: No idea if it's a dupe or not, but they awarded a 500 points bounty on that question. Hardly a rep-gaining proposition.

Comment: They were the user that awarded that bounty. If you hover over the bounty, you'll see which user awarded it.

Comment: (Tangentially, and also for @Temani: Since we do not know Lostsoul's gender, using the gender neutral _they_ would probably be appropriate)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Uhh I'm slightly confused ... the accepted answer received a bounty of 250 rep yet LostSoul put a bounty of 500 rep ... what's happened then??

Comment: read how bounty works ... this is the automatic award system, that award half the the bounty if there is no manual award. So before accusing people better verify ;)

Comment: @yivi Seeing the recent blog post, I agree :-)  (note my initial use of (s)he )

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm removing my accusation as it has been made on false premises ... thanks!

Comment: @TemaniAfif Interestingly enough, it turns out LostSoul asked a third duplicate of the question ... see my edit to the question.

Comment: i guess you should call LostSoul here to have clarification ;) ... I am not experienced with the topics, and the question are very well written and they are bounty awarded (so they got featured for a week), so people for sure did notice a similarity ... so let's give @LostSoul a chance to explain us.

Comment: Another take on it on Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/70798/250755

Comment: And on Stats.SE: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/341588.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks! I'll edit those into my question.

Comment: Presenting a problem without any hint whatsoever that it was tabled before is pretty jackass, but not uncommon.  The most depressing thing about it is that there were so many users, other than you, that could not find those previous questions.  When Google can't index SO anymore then we might as well quit.  Closing as dup is the correct way to handle this, it is gathering votes.

Comment: @HansPassant Should I vote for all but one of these questions to be closed as dupes?

Comment: At least his 2nd question links the 1st one, so it is okay.  Ish.  You already correctly voted for the 3rd question.

Comment: @yivi Using he in this case is also completely appropriate https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30455/is-using-he-for-a-gender-neutral-third-person-correct

Comment: @LostSoul I feel your presence is required here ;-)

Comment: @Adi you can't 'summon' a user to a thread like this. Comment on something they were active on and point them here :)

Comment: @Patrice Are you sure?? I used it on a previous post on another SE site  and the user I was 'summoning' replied within minutes ... (I'll try your method, just in case)

Comment: @Adi 100%. He won't get the ping unless he was already involved in the question in some way shape or form. Imagine how many people would ping Jon Skeet with 'answer this plz' if this was a feature.  You may have just been lucky before I guess

Comment: That's true 

Comment: @Oleg; I know, but I think that using “they” is generally accepted to be more inclusive. And it costs literally nothing.

Comment: @yivi Reading your posts with the forced(to my eyes) they makes me cringe. To me that's a hefty cost.

Comment: @yivi: Some of us still believe that *they* is a plural pronoun. Using it as a singular pronoun creates all kinds of grammatical grief: Should the verb take a plural or singular form in such cases? In the first instance, *they awarded*, it doesn't matter. But in the second instance, *they were the user*, your sentence is self-inconsistent. If you meant to use a singular *they*, you should have written *They was the user*. It's not nearly as simple as "Language changes, get over it and don't be a dinosaur". Very real issues must be addressed before (ab)using *they* as singular.

Comment: @BenVoigt If I were you, that would be singular.

Comment: @Cœur: I'm not sure what you're getting at. First vs second vs third person does affect the verb form as well, but we clearly are discussing only third person singular and third person plural here.  Third person singular determines the verb form... which grates on the ear when paired with *they*, but must be correct if *they* is singular.  Subjunctive voice (which appears in your comment) also affects verb form, but the sentence in question was not counterfactual. Did you mean that the singular gender-unspecified third person pronoun should be *that* rather than *they*?